# Express + knex + Objection Base service class

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, knex.js, objection.js

I'm looking for solution to use BaseService for common Objection model methods. it is working properly on UserService. but i want to write some methods in BaseService class.

base.service.ts

```
class BaseService<Models>{
  public m: Models;

  constructor(model: Models) {
    this.m = model;
  }

  //Not working
  public find(): Promise<any> {
    return await this.m.query().findAll();
  }

}
```

user.service.ts

```
class UserService extends BaseService<typeof UserMoodel> {
    constructor() {
        super(UserModel)
    }

    getUsers() : Promise<User> {
        return await this.m.query().findAll().toCast<User>();
    }
}
```

user.model.ts

```
class UserMoodel extends Model {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try out [feathers](https://docs.feathersjs.com/) It has good community, It has some learning curve but since you know knex then you can easily adopt it.